# Is there a way to remove padding from Google TTS output?

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I'm using Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1 and using TextToSpeechClient.SynthesizeSpeech() to generate an Mp3 of some basic ssml. However, the results always come back with roughly 50ms of padded silence at the start of the file and 200ms of padded silence at the end.

Is there a way to prevent this padding being added as I need to have these mp3s play as stitched-together sentences and the padding adds unnecessary pauses.

Just to be clear, an example of the ssml I am using:

```
<speak>Hello</speak>
```

I am not adding any breaks or pauses of my own.

Comment: Behaviours like this, that are not adjustable, are rather infuriating and make the API harder to use for any serious purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found solution in GOOGLE TTS api, but i have found 2 workarounds

1) Javascript

Since i play sound in JS i just position play time before playing like this

```
var au=new Audio(url);
au.preload=true;
au.currentTime=0.15;
```

and then attache event handler to update play time event:

```
function stopp(e){
    if (e.target.currentTime >= e.target.duration-0.3) {
        e.target.pause();
        e.target.removeEventListener('timeupdate',stopp);
    }
}
au.addEventListener('timeupdate',stopp, false)
```

so the sound is stooped before the end

2) Using SOX preprocessing

SOX (Sound eXchange, the Swiss Army knife of audio manipulation)
can cut silence from mp3 files. HOWEVER cutting at the end if crazy. You need to
reverse the file, cut the beginning and the reverse again. I actually did not find
any utility which can easily cut silence at the end of file.

Have you found a better solution by now?